# Обработка каждого нового события

Tags: c#, события

Есть своё событие

```
public event EventHandler e1;
```

Вызываю его с помощью

```
e1?.Invoke(null, null);
```

Привязываю его к методу через

```
e1 += e1_click;
```

И обрабатываю через

```
private void e1_click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

А теперь вопрос: если у меня будет, допустим, 10 вызовов события в секунду, а обработка одного вызова занимает 5 секунд, то оставшиеся 49 вызовов просто никак не обработаются и проигнорируются?

Как создать очередь вызовов, что бы был обработан каждый вызов, не зависимо от времени?

При этом так же нужно, что бы обработка шла в многопотоке

Comment: Ну вы реально с проблемой столкнулись или просто интересно стало? Если всё происходит в одном потоке, то все по очереди отработают.

Comment: @АндрейNOP реальный вопрос. Я посылаю на обработку 10 сообщений, при этом, в зависимости от ситуации, они могут быть обработаны как за 0.01 сек, так и за 20 сек. И мне нужно, что бы из-за сообщения, на которое ушло 20 сек, не пропали следующие сообщения, которые пришли, пока обрабатывалось то сообщение.

Comment: Ок, запускаете как? Таймер или что? Если таймер, то какой?

Comment: @АндрейNOP нет. Мне пришло сообщение от сервера, я его привожу в нужный мне формат, и отправляю как объект события (пока только мысли, ещё не реализовано).

Comment: Можно через агрегацию событий сделать. В одном потоке просто складируете полученные данные и формируете большой пакет. Потом дергаете другое событие, в котором передаете пакет на длительную обработку в другой поток. Варианты разные есть.

Comment: Внутри обработчика события запускайте `Task`.

Answer (score 0):

Обработка событий происходит в одном потоке в том же, в котором вы вызываете это событие. То есть вы не сможете сделать десять вызовов в секунду, так как следующий вызов события произойдет только после того, как отработают все обработчики. По сути event можно заменить списком делегатов.